# Can this model be implemented with lme4?

Tags: lme4-nlme

Suppose the data $y_{ijk}$ is structured with three indexes $i,j$ and $k$, and can be decomposed through a linear mixed-effects model:

$y_{ijk}=a + b_i + \xi_j+ \eta_k + \gamma_{jk} + \epsilon_{ijk}$

where $a$ and $b_i$ are fixed effects, $\xi_j$ and $\eta_k$ are two random-effect terms associated with the two grouping factors indexed with $j$ and $k$, respectively, $\gamma_{jk}$ is the interaction effect between the two indexes, and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the residual term.

My distribution assumptions are

$\xi_j \sim N(0, \tau^2)$

$\eta_k \sim N(0, \lambda^2)$

$\gamma_{jk} \sim N(0, \theta_k^2)$

$\epsilon_{ijk} \sim N(0, \sigma_k^2)$

Notice that the last two distributions are unique in the sense that they are separately modeled for each $k$. So, is there a way to analyze the data with the R package lme4? Through dummy coding somehow?

If the residuals cannot be partitioned across $k$ with lme4, is it still possible to at least keep $\gamma_{jk} \sim N(0, \theta_k^2)$?

Comment: Perhaps consider the `TMB` R-package?